# Are default arguments in functions an equal alternative for local variable declarations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, global-variables, hoisting

***Note: This is about declaring LOCAL variables (function-scoped variables).***

I have just realized that when I have an JavaScript function whose callers I contorl (e.g. not public API), I can "**safely**" simplify the declaration and assignment of *local* variables and get rid of `var`/`const`/`let` at the same time.

The method exploits default function arguments to a) declare a function-scoped variable and b) even assign it:

```
// BEFORE
function createDashes(count) {
  let dash ="-";            // declare a variable for use in the function
  for (let i=0; i < count; i++) {
    dash += "-";
  }
  return dash;
}
console.log(createDashes(5)); // "-----"

// AFTER
function createDashes(count, dash="-") {
  for (let i=0; i < count; i++) {
    dash += "-";
  }
  return dash;
}
console.log(createDashes(5)); // "-----"
```

Overall, with this technique we can declare an arbitrary (but fixed) number of variables with or without assignments:

```
// var0 - var2 are variables without assignments (i.e. initialized to undefined)
// var3 - var4 are variables with assignments (must come after the previous ones!)
function foo(actualParameter, var0, var1, var2, var3="x", var4="y") {
  // ...
}
```

There is also no performance penalty in doing this technique.

> **QUESTION: What are the limitations or restrictions of this method?**

[Reading through the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> The function arguments is an **Array-like object** accessible
> **inside** functions that contain the values of the arguments passed to that function.
>
> The arguments object **is a local variable available within all
> non-arrow functions**. You can refer to a function's arguments inside
> that function by using its arguments object. It has entries for each
> argument the function was called with, with the first entry's index at
> 0.

Comment: How do you know there is no performance penalty? Did you consult JS VMs' implementations? I also think that perhaps an example other than the dash function would be better. Since there, you don't even need a variable for holding `"-"`. Also, you can simplify it overall to just `const creatDashes = "-".repeat` defeating your purpose of example :)

Comment: I agree @ComFreek. The example is just a bad example.

Comment: @ComFreek. Your edits are very useful. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated yourself, the major limitation of this technique is that one has to "*be careful not to overwrite such variable by mistake by incorrect function calls*". It's also not clear at all which of the function parameters were meant as optional parameters and which were meant as local variables. You will also experience difficulties when documenting your functions signatures, or when refactoring the code.

As with so many techniques that allow shorter syntax, it's good for golfing but will lead to unreadable, hard-to-maintain and unidiomatic code.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. I agree. It is interesting to know and keep in mind though.

Comment: It's a fairly [standard technique in code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204269/7588) afaict. But there's really no other applications where you'd want to avoid normal variable declarations.